# Can I set the name of variable with textbox? VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can I set the name of the variable with TextBox (Vba Excel)?
I have to input new group of products on the way that I write the name of the group in TextBox and click command button.
The code have to take the String from Textbox an set this string as name of new created array.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your effort

Comment: No way. But why would you want to change the name of a variable?

Comment: @FunThomas: No That is not true You can create variables at runtime. Unfortunately this is not documented anywhere (Or at least I have not read about it anywhere)

Comment: Actually I don't want to change the name of the variable. I just want to create a new variable (or array) at runtime.
I need to check if the string in the TextBox allready exist in the list of the variables and if not then create a new variable named as this string in TextBox.

Comment: Use a collection or dictionary?

Comment: `I just want to create a new variable (or array) at runtime.` You can do that but it is not recommended. Using a Collection/Dictionary is recommended as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254337/how-to-create-dynamic-variable-names-vba)

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout: You can create objects, but *create* a variable that *holds* this object? And this is added to the symbol table at runtime? How would you access this in your code (without compile error)? My brain is too small to even understand all the implications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not advisable to do that. You could however program your own classe with would then hold your `GroupName` and `Data`. I usually use `collections` as data containers opposed to arrays. A class `MyClass` would then look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TModel
    Data As Collection
    GroupName as string
End Type

Private this As TModel

Public Property Get GroupName() As Collection
    Set GroupName= this.GroupName
End Property
Public Property Let GroupName(ByVal Value As Collection)
    Set this.GroupName= Value
End Property
Public Property Get Data() As Collection
    Set Data = this.Data
End Property
Public Property Let Data(ByVal Value As Collection)
    Set this.Data = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set this.Data = New Collection
End Sub
```

This looks pretty complicated but actually is very simple. You have a encapsulation using the Private Type `TModel`. There you store the data. Using `Property Get` and `Property Let` you can then get and let your property of the class. This may be used like this in a `Module`.

```
Sub TestMyClass()
Dim MClass as New MyClass
Dim GName as String
Dim Data as New Collection

Set Data=GetData()
GName=GetName()

Set MClass.Data=Data
Set MClass.GroupName=GName

Debug.Print MClass.GroupName ' Prints Groupname
End Sub
```

Like this every Variable of the type `MyClass` has a name and data in it.

Answer (score 4):

> I just want to create a new variable (or array) at runtime.

It is believed that ***this is not possible***. But it is. This is not documented anywhere (at least I have not read it anywhere).

**Logic**:

We will simply program The VBA Editor at runtime to create new array. You can read more about programming the VBA editor at Chip's website [Programming The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

**Note**

1. Ensure you have set a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3`
2. I am not doing any error handling. Feel free to incorporate that in your code.

In the below code we will create an array `MyArray` and dimension it to say a size of `5`

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const vbext_ct_StdModule As Integer = 1

Sub Sample()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long

    Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)

    '~~> Create new module called MySpecialModule
    '~~> It it exists then you will get an error
    '~~> Either delete it and create new one or use error handling
    VBComp.Name = "MySpecialModule"

    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "Public MyArray() As String"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "Public Sub InitArray()"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "    Redim MyArray (1 to 5)"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
    End With

    '~~> Initialize newly created Array
    initializeArray
End Sub

'~~> Run the procedure to initialize the newly created array
Sub initializeArray()
    InitArray

    Debug.Print UBound(MyArray)
End Sub
```

When you run the code, a new module is created and some code is injected in that module. That code is then again called at runtime. The below code doesn't exists when you run the code.

```
Public MyArray() As String

Public Sub InitArray()
    ReDim MyArray(1 To 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hehe, I like that. And then put an `On error resume next` when checking if a variable already exists. And of course remove the Module at the end. Debugging is not possible (throws an error) - noone will be able to understand your code...

Comment: Such questions inspire me to create blogs on my website. Created a blogpost on [Create a new variable/object at runtime](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2019/03/22/create-a-new-variable-object-at-runtime/) :D